# Calling static method from external application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following static function that exports to be called from external application

```
[DllExport("Initialize", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static void OnStartUp1( )
{
    try
    {
        a = new Indicator();
        a.Init();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

    }
}
```

when I used and call this method from .NET another application it is working well but when I call it from the external application that I build this function for it is return the following exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException: DragDrop registration did not succeed. ---> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

Comment: Did you try marking the method with the attribute [STAThread] ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the same apartment. The error indicates that it must be called from an application with the same apartment (Single Threaded Apartment or STA). Therefore, your calling application must be STA.

To make it STA, you need the `[STAThread]` attribute on your main method.

This has to do with COM. Some COM components can only be accessed by a single thread so they are hosted in an STA. Some are made thread-safe and be accessed by multiple threads so they are hosted in Multi Threaded Apartment (MTA). When you are calling these COM components you must match that apartment.

You will notice windows forms applications will have main method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
}
```

Most like the .NET application, with which it is working and you do not get that error, has this `[STAThread]` attribute on its main method.

Comment: I don't have Main procedure but I used this

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); and it is solved the message but the form that running is not accessible

Comment: It is like freezed form.

Comment: Well i am not sure what kind of app you have if it is not .Net.  Find out how to do this on your type of application because the way you did it may not be correct.

Comment: The external application is MT4 and the above code working if I called it from .NET app but when calling it from MT4 it is freezing the form that run.

Comment: It would freeze if the calling thread does not have a message loop.